# DB2/C# Fun with queries and strings - Problems building query

Tags: c#, string, db2, ibm-midrange

I've been tasked with what so far seems not possible but I was hoping that someone better at sql queries then me could figure this out if it's possible.  I'm having problems querying data from a table.  The source of the problem is I'm forced to query on names an date of birth.  The date of birth is working and is out of the scope of my issue.  My goal is to query using common values in both the source (an excel report) and the destination (the database) and thats the last name.

Fields:  Name1, Name2
Table: Participant

Name2 in the database contains last name but if the person uses a middle name or a suffix it also contains those values.  The source (report) for the most part contains only last names but sometimes it also has a small number of middle names also mixed into the last name.  My goal is to strip out the middle name and suffix from the database query and also from the report last name string.

From the Database:
I need to strip the middle name which is to the left of the last name in the name2 field.  They are separated by a space.  I will also need to strip the suffix if it exists after the last name.

From the Report:
I need to strip out the middle name which would be to the left of the last name separated by a space.  This would be done in c#

Please let me know if I can provide any more info to help with an answer.

My first guess with the query part is to do a wildcard search in which I would obtain the last name from the report and query the table using a (like '%%').  I think this will obtain the record I'm looking for in a search but I'm not sure how well it will work.

Comment: Could you not retrieve the whole field and then use the split method of String to split it on spaces? (for the C# part, still thinking about the query)

Comment: Do you need to do anything more than join the corresponding rows from the report and the database? If that is all you need to do, and the last name field in the report is always a subset of the last name field in the database, then I think the approach you suggest in your last paragraph will be the best bet.

Comment: This is a very common but very difficult problem. There are software packages out there specifically for handling messy, real-world data. If you have the stomach for it, you can roll your own. (Yes, it's ugly, with lots of special cases and magic constants.) Ultimately, I don't think you're going to get a "clean" query directly linking your data sources. You will more likely have to build a separate, cleaned-up version of one or both of the data sources, and then query the cleaned-up data. (And that cleaned-up data won't be perfect either, but it should be close enough.)

Comment: Please don't forget to vote up my question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As John Clifford suggests, you could grab the last name using split like so (pseudocode):

```
// If the string contains a space, split it
string surname = Name2;
int spacePos = surname.IndexOf(" ");
if (spacePos > 0)
{
    string[] words = surname.Split(' ');
    surname = words[1];
}
```

Or you could find the space, and then get a substring:

```
int spaceTruckin = Name2.IndexOf(" ");
string surname = Name2.Substring(spaceTruckin);
```

Comment: The middle name/suffix is the thing that's vexing me. If it's a case of the field just containing 1-3 strings separated by spaces, there isn't really going to be a way to differentiate what's a middle name and what's a suffix.

Comment: I reckon you'd have to count spaces to determine it. Of course, that could get complicated based on all the different possibilities (Edgar Hoover, Edgar Hoover, esquire, etc.) - or if the data is inconistent, such as "Edgar Hoover,esq" (no second space).

Comment: The issue I'm imagining is that you could have "surname suffix" or "middlename surname" which have the same number of spaces. I suppose if the suffixes do have a comma or a full stop or something it'd be easier to figure out which is which.

Comment: I think you can figure out the suffix.  MiddeName LastName Suffix .. What will throw this off is if the person had multiple word middle names.  I also have a person with a 3 part last name separated by spaces which will be very difficult.

Comment: Yes, it boils down to a laissez-faire approach to storing data. The best thing would be to clean up the data.

Comment: @Mike With the schema you're using would it be possible to have separate fields to middle name, surname and suffix? That would make this much easier.

Comment: @JohnClifford No.  This is queried from production and I have no power to change any of the table in the database in reference to the name.   With DB2 programming I'm unable to change most production tables due to their archaic programming language in which a new column will screw up their programs.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon you have an error in the above with s.Split  there is no object s.  That should be surname.split

Comment: I'm going to have to count the words.  I just see some potential problems when dealing with situations where multiple middle names could throw it off.  I'm going to exclude anything >3 words.

Comment: :( i see an issue with @B.ClayShannon approach.  How do I differentiate a LastName Suffix from a middlename Last name combination??  The only way I see I can do that is to do a string comparison of known suffix's.  This sucks!

Comment: Yes, it was only pseudocode; it shows how important it is to design databases correctly - with a column for each type of data (middle name, suffix, etc.)

Comment: @B.ClayShannon I work for a mom and pop shop.  I completely agree.  You dont want to know what the databases look like here.

Comment: @Mike: You have to look for the humor in such situations; otherwise you will get a bad case of keyboardrage.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon we've been thinking about this in reverse.  I need to query the database which has the suffix's and the middle names.  The report does not have those values.  Currently I'm retriving no records because the database has those stored but the report doesnt.  I need to join the value LastName from the report to the database query to locate the person which contains suffix's and middle names.

Comment: The only solution I see so far is to use LIKE on the name field and use '%LASTNAME%' wildcard to query the last name within the name field.

Comment: Note that it's not always necessary to change a table's definition. You might also create a new VIEW that existing programs won't even know about much less be affected by. Also, there can be numerous "last names" that have actual embedded spaces as part of the name. A LIKE wildcard might be okay, but short lastnames can be found as parts of longer lastnames -- LIKE '%JOHN%' would match 'JOHNSON', etc.

Comment: @user2338816 you're correct but I am qualifying it with other fields such as DOB, and sex.  If there is a chance where multiple people are queried I send it to an exception table.  Like and name fields are terrible identifiers and I've let the business know that but this is what I've been given to work with and I was told to do what I can with what was given.  A view is a good idea but the problem is there are some real nasty combinations when middle name is thrown in the mix.

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar table with an... integrated 'last name'.

I ended up writing a UDF that did the best it could, but there are still situations I haven't coded for which pop up from time to time.  I wrote my UDF in ILE RPG.  Unlike most databases, DB2 for i allows me to write in a HLL and simply register it as as UDF.  I mention this because it's possible that the developers on the IBM side have already written the code to split the name parts - all they need to do now is make a UDF.  Then you could

```
select getLast(combinedName) from ...
```

Comment: Probably the best choice. A UDF could always be extended to handle more (and more complex) cases as they became known.

Comment: I'm not an AS400 programmer.  I have no idea what this is

Comment: UDF is User Defined Function; bog standard SQL.  My point was to ask the IBM i programmers if they already have code that splits the name.  If so, they can re-use it and wrap it in a UDF that you can execute in your SELECT statements.